# Should I tape joints during or after an initial fill with setting-type compound?

Tags: drywall, spackling-paste

I am spreading 90min quick set, followed by green lid to finish off. I am using the quick set because I have to add multiple layers to help build up uneven seams.

**My question is:**

- At what point should I add tape in these instances? I was thinking once I'm done layering and ready to add finishing coats, that is when I will add my tape? Or is it pointless given how many layers I'm adding of quickset to build up the uneven seam, or is it too late?

Pictures:

- wall 1 in it's almost finished state of layering with quick set, if you look closely, you can still see a bit of a hump that I'm going to work out with another coat or 2 before green lid finishing
- wall 2 showing beginning stages of layering and uneven seams I am working with

(sorry if the images are rotated --- I had corrected them on my end but they don't seem to carry over sometimes)

Yes, I could have taken the sheetrock down, reworked the studs to match the existing, or shimmed, but I'm beyond that now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is mostly a matter of opinion--I've heard that tape closer to the surface performs better. It's also a matter of your workflow--I'd rather set tape in standard mud than setting-type mud for ease of work.

Comment: definitely tape early. As long as you don't go overboard with the hot mud, and you're careful about feathering out the top layers of all-purpose, *and* you don't get carried away with sanding, this approach will work fine.

Answer (score 7):

Tape goes in early. The tape is providing a paper face across the joint just as the paper face of the board does across the wallboard surface, and wants to be bonded as close to that surface as possible.  So, it's generally embedded in the first coat of mud. Mud, tape, mud over tape, build up to a smooth surface.

You are not spackling, you are mudding joints (applying joint compound, which is somewhat universally called mud.) Spackle is a different product for a different purpose.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I understand tape goes on early (first application) to join seams, but wouldn't that change in this instance where the two seams are extremely uneven and need to first be built up to an even plane, then be taped? @Ecnerwal

Comment: No, that does not change when tape goes on, though you're obviously long past the ideal point for tape already. Shimming would have saved you a bunch of work at this stage, of course.

Comment: As I mentioned above, opinions vary. The very talented pro team we employed for many years would do heavy fill first and come back and tape later.

Comment: @isherwood - my apologies friend, I did not see your first post immediately under mine. I was under the same method of application as you had mentioned.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is true, long past that point on that one particular wall. I'm still going to add tape, I just hope everything underneath that helped initially fill the uneven seam doesn't crack

Comment: It's unlikely to crack however you do it unless you have extreme temperature changes or movement in your wall. Just git 'r done! :)

Comment: @isherwood I love it! thanks for your input/contributions - have a great weekend!